# Jupyter notebook auto indentation doesn't work for scala

Tags: scala, jupyter-notebook

I have being using jupyter notebook from the anaconda distribution for quite awhile, and I have installed both Python 2 and 3, and R kernels. They all work fine.

Recently, however, after I installed scala kernel, everything works fine except for the auto indentation, i.e. the cursor always sits at the beginning of a line after the enter is hit, and this problem only occurs in scala notebook.

I have tried jupyter-scala and Apache toree. They both have this issue. This issue is troublesome, for example, when you write nested loops as you have to tab the mouse cursor to the right position on every new line.

I have tried the conventional methods such as modifying the custom.js file, and issuing the mirrorcode commands on the browser console to set the indentUnit. It has effect on Python and R notebooks but Scala notebook just won't change.

Highly appreciate your help! I have been bothered by this issue for awhile now. Thank you very much in advance!